# Start Debugging and Start without Debugging -- different values in Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my wpf app I'm using `Properties.Settings.Default` to save the application settings. Surprisingly, when I'm running it the Debug **mode** (Start Debugging F5) and without Debugging (Start without Debugging Ctrl+F5) I get different values saved in `Properties.Settings.Default`. I wonder, why is that and how to make them the same?

Comment: The files generated for debug and non debug mode are different. (They are not same programs ;))

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, so how to make them use the same Settings?

Comment: Here is a good answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469904/settings-setting-gives-the-different-values-in-debug-mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469904/settings-setting-gives-the-different-values-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score 2):

While debugging from VS, the IDE uses `<your application>.vshost.exe` process to host your application instead of running it directly. This causes your configuration changes being saved for `<your application>.vshost.exe` instead of `<your application>.exe`.

What you can do is to disable this default behavior by going to project settings and unchecking `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` option in `Debug` tab.